# Html.TextareaFor in partial view C#

Tags: c#, lambda, html-helper

In our application we use HtmlHelpers and partial views to create components.  For the Commentbox component, how can I generate a textbox using a given model property?
The code below is the holy grail, but gives some errors.

**Code (simplified)**

*/Views/Comment.cshtml (the page)*

```
@Html.Commentbox(m => m.Message);
```

*/Extensions/HtmlHelper.cs (the intermediate helper)*

```
public static MvcHtmlString FormTextbox<TModel, TProperty>( this HtmlHelper<TModel > htmlHelper,
       Expression<Func <TModel , TProperty >> CommentboxExpression, CommentboxViewModel model = null)
{
    if (model == null) { model = new CommentboxViewModel(); }
    model.ModelItem = CommentboxExpression;
    return htmlHelper.Partial( "Components/Commentbox", model);
}
```

*/ViewModels/Components/CommentboxViewModel.cs (the ViewModel)*

```
namespace ViewModels.Components
{
    public class CommentboxViewModel
    {
        public LambdaExpression ModelItem { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*/Components/Commentbox.cshtml (the component partial view)*

```
@model ViewModels.Components.CommentboxViewModel
@Html.TextAreaFor(Model.ModelItem)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model.ModelItem)
```

**What doesn't work:**

- `@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ModelItem)` (in partialview) -> puts "m => m.ModelItem" as value into the textarea box
- `@Html.TextAreaFor(Model.ModelItem)` (in partialview) -> gives "The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextAreaFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

**What worked:**

- it works using `@Html.TextArea()`, but then you need to manually add validation attributes.
- it works when generating a `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` as MvcHtmlString on the ViewModel, but we want to keep as much possible of the rendering in the partial view and possibly nest components.

**Question**

How to get `@Html.TextAreaFor(Model.ModelItem)` working in the partial view, so it renders a textbox, including all validation attributes?

Comment: What is the point of this? What html are you actually trying to render? (this is not the way to use a `HtmlHelper` extension method)

Comment: This makes it easy to create a view using components. Using the `TagBuilder` in `HtmlHelper` is not read-friendly, but `PartialView` is. Or do you have another method in mind?

In this example only a textarea and validation message must be rendered on the page. But in real life the html could be far more complex.

Comment: Having a `HtmlHelper` which calls a partial is crazy (you cannot even compile it into a separate assembly as its now dependent on other files) - and you may as well just call the partial directly. The whole purpose of creating an extension method is to output html, not call another view.